# How does the wronskian teste for linear independence?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

It is true that if a set of $n$ functions, $(f_n)$, are $n-1$ times differentiable and de wronskian of this set is nonzero in a point, these functions are linearly independent. Any proof for that?

Comment: It seems that if they are linearly dependent, a linear combination of the wronskian's columns vanishes.

Comment: Indeed, if the $f_n$ were linearly dependent, then their Wronskian would vanish everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can prove the contrapositive of the statement like this: consider $n$ linearly dependent functions $f_i(t),1\le i\le n$ all $n-1$ times differentiable in the given domain of $t$. Then $\exists c_1,...,c_n$ not all $0$ such that $\forall t$,

$c_1f_1+...+c_nf_n=0\\c_1f_1'+...+c_nf_n'=0\\~~~~\vdots\\c_1f_1^{(n-1)}+...+c_nf^{(n-1)}_n=0$

WLOG assume $c_1\ne0$. The Wronskian is given by$$\begin{vmatrix}f_1&f_2&\ldots&f_n\\f_1'&f_2'&\ldots&f_n'\\\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\f_1^{(n-1)}&f_2^{(n-1)}&\ldots&f_n^{(n-1)}\end{vmatrix}$$Now operate $C_1\to C_1+\frac1{c_1}\sum_{j=2}^nc_jC_j$ and satisfy yourself that this operation makes the first column zero, giving the Wronskian zero $\forall t$.